# UIImageView Resizing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

On my storyboard I have a UIImageView which doesn't take up the whole screen, as intended.  At runtime the image takes up the whole screen, which is a problem because I want to add some buttons on the top.

Here is where I assign the picture to the view:

```
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"floors.png"];
```

And here are the relevant screenshots:

[image: UIImageView in storyboard (doesn't take up full view)]
[image: At runtime, when it takes up full view and overlaps 'Button']

How can I get the image to stay the same size as on the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Set view mode of imageview to scale To Fill in storyboard

Another option to check is whether you are setting the autolayout properly